# Eclipse Auto Whitespace Disable

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, code-formatting

Before Eclipse Oxygen (Eclipse Neon) I would be able to type:

```
while(condition){

}
```

and it would look like it does. Now in Oyxgen, when I type the above, a space is automatically added after the close bracket, like so:

```
while(condition) {

}
```

How can I disable this auto space? I am not used to it, and all of my other code does not have it. It is extremely inconvenient to have to click into its position and backspace every time I write a statement.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck the following preference:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing
-> Automatically insert at correct position -> Braces
```

Comment: This. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear lord! Thank you! That was driving me crazy..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: From the main menu go to `Window -> Preferences`. Then go to `Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`, `Edit...` and choose `White Space` tab. On the left menu go to `Control statements -> Blocks` and uncheck `before opening brace` and `OK`. This is on Eclipse Neon. The Eclipse Oxygen menu may be slightly different but this is the main idea.